# Display new Activity on top of previous Activity but only partially cover the previous Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

[image: Flow of desired behaviour]

I have an Activity A which has a "down" button (see image above). When I press this button, I want to launch an Activity B on top of Activity A such that some of Activity A at the bottom is still visible. Activity B can in turn launch a number of other Activities (C, D etc) such that they only display within the same screen area as B. Does anybody know whether this is possible and, if so, how I can go about it?

#### Edit

I am aware that I can add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to my Activity's manifest declaration. However, as far as I am aware, this displays in the centre of the screen and not such that I can resize it how I require. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the XML for activities that should be on top of Activity A:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="#000000" >
        //use this for your new activity contents
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#00000000" >
        //this is empty
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in your **manifest** for Activities B, C etc:

```xml
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".ActivityB"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

In **values/styles.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">  
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/theme_transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally, in **drawable/theme_transparent.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#00000000" ></solid>
</shape>
```

Comment: @AdilHussain I just fixed a small typo so be careful

Comment: Looks good Sherif. Thanks. A simplification I found is to set the activity theme in the manifest to "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" and then we don't need to define the style and shape in the res/values and res/drawable folders. Also, a single LinearLayout in the layout file with the height, width and background specified as required I found is sufficient, and no need to specify two LinearLayouts (with weights) contained within a main LinearLayout object. Thanks again. A huge help.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to use, are [Fragments.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Fragments can be used to fill a part of the screen, while doing something else entirely in a different one.
In your example you can create a main activity that contains two `Fragments`.  One `Fragment` controls the "A activity" , the other one controls the "B activity"  and the other ones..
By replacing the current `Fragment` in your "B activity" area with a different one on the press of a button, you can achieve the behavior you are looking for. At least, that's how I did it in an app of mine containing a main content area and a music player. The music player stays in place while the main content changes.

Sadly I can't provide any example code right now, but here is a tutorialthat should help you get started:

- [Android User Interface Design: Working With Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

In case you are working with an Android version below 3.0, you can use the Compatibility package.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Comment: Hey Sander, I've gone with Sherif's solution for now of starting up an Activity which only covers the screen as specified but might need to come back to Fragments for a forthcoming problem where I'll need some elements of Activity A interact-able even whilst B is loaded up...

Comment: Then you'll have to resort to `Fragments` yeah. Just a warning, you will need to refactor all your activities into fragments for it to work properly, which is a real pain once you start it, but it's worth it.

Comment: Hey Sander, do you know if it's possible to change the visible area of a Fragment whilst the app is running. So, for example, Fragment B (containing Activity B) is invisible but if I press the down button on Fragment A (containing Activity A), then Fragment B comes into view overlapping Fragment A (as in my picture above)?

Comment: Certainly, I'm doing the same in my app. I have a two fragments, one is my main content and the other is a music player. If I press a button on the music player it collapses, being replaced by a different fragment which shows a button to open it again. 
But, if the user wants to, they can completely remove the player in total, which just sets the player's visibility to `GONE`.

Comment: Got it working, thanks again Sander. A huge help. Much much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem :) Good to see you got it to work. It takes a while to get used to, but once you get the hang of it you will never want to go back ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your "**Edit**", actually, you can move around / resize a Dialog themed activity.
For example, to make your Dialog themed activity appear at the top of the screen instead of the default center and be 80% width of the screen, just add the following after `setContentView` in your Dialog themed activity:

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.80);
window.setLayout(screenWidth, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```