# Cant get gravity to bottom on "overlay activity"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm trying to create and overlay that displays on top of another activity, in the bottom. however i can't seem to get it to go to the bottom. It just stays in the middle, and has the height and width as the 2 buttons that are in it.

i have tried the solutions in this question:
[Display new Activity on top of previous Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503653/display-new-activity-on-top-of-previous-activity)

But that didn't do it.

So basically i'm down to this simple layout again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#000" android:weightSum="0.6">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
        android:text="text2"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".Overlay_share" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"></activity>
```

And in my styles:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/semitransparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
<color name="semitransparent">#00000000</color> 
</resources>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you can do this with a linear layout but i'd suggest a relative one.

1. Change match_parent to fill_parent for your layout
2. You need to specify android:gravity="bottom" for the buttons individually
3. If you need the buttons to have equal weights, you should add another LinearLayout that wraps the buttons and specifies a weightSum and have the buttons specify individual **layout_weight** for the buttons.

So **fill_parent**, a nested LinearLayout for the buttons that specifies a **weightSum** and uses **wrap_content**, and specify **layout_weight** for the individual buttons. Or a RelativeLayout as i'll try to demonstrate below.

Here's how i'd suggest (personally)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#000">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
    android:text="text1"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
    android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
    android:text="text2"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or **LinearLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#000">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
    android:text="text1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/greybutton"
    android:text="text2"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully this at least gets you on the right track

Comment: Using A Relativelayout with a linearlayout inside, did the trick without much hassle! So your very first comment really was the simplest :o) , thank you!