# Display new Activity on top of main Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503653/display-new-activity-on-top-of-previous-activity), but slightly more complicated. The general idea is to seek the behaviour represented in the following image

[image]

That is a main activity running with a chunk of another activity in the top (or bottom) of the screen, which can be dragged down/up to almost fully cover the main activity.

The main difficulties are

- *New Activity* is in another project different than the *Main Activity*
- While the chunk of the *New Activity* is visible, I must be able to keep using all the features of the *Main Activity*
- The other project in which *New Activity* is defined is a JAR library, so I won't be able to access any XML file or any resource different than java code
- **Edit:** I only develop the library (and use it as a jar), I don't have any control over the main activity

So far I've been trying to set the *New Activity* background to transparency, but due to the lack of XML files and because both activities are in different projects (and my lack of experience using android) I only get a black background.

So I would like to know if all of this is even possible and how can I make it work.

Thanks in advanced!
Best regards,
Warren.

Comment: Something like `newActivity.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);` might work if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: @Jakar thanks for replaying! I guess that copy the setting of a dialog window into the new activity, because if I touch the screen outside the borders the new activity is closed :c

Comment: I forgot about that. You have to have the permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and call `newActivity.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`. I think that's right. I found it from searching. I've never actually used it in my code, though.

Comment: If I keep the dialog theme line then the new activity still closes. If I remove it then I have the same result I've reached so far, the new activity shows itself but with a black background :c